# free extension to edit homepage

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I'm working on magento and my client want me to edit homepage. I'm not good at coding, so I'm looking for some extension to edit homepage. I tried many ways but didn't get an extension. Please suggest me some free magento extension to edit homepage, like moving column from one place another. Thanks

Comment: No need for "coding" but maybe you should go learn about [Magento layout XML configuration](http://alanstorm.com/new_book_no_frills_magento_layout) if you **work** with Magento for a **client**.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Magento admin. Go to `CMS -> Pages -> Home page` and edit it there in Content section.

You don't get extension for everything in Magento.